# Why is the source of the EM Field in QED the probability current and not the electric current?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

I have some problems understanding the interaction term in the QED Lagrangian. If we take

$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \bar \psi (\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi+\bar \psi \gamma^\mu\psi e A_\mu
$$

and perform the gauge transformation $A_\mu \to \partial_\mu \alpha$ and $\psi\to e^{i e\alpha}\psi$ we obtain the following conserved current via the Noether theorem:

$\partial_\mu j^\mu = 0$ with $j^\mu=\bar \psi \gamma^\mu \psi$. The respective Noether charge is then:

$$
Q=\int d^3x\mathop{} j^0=\int d^3x \mathop{}\bar \psi \gamma^0 \psi = \int d^3x\mathop{} \psi^\dagger\psi
$$

Since this is the magnitude of the vector squared I assume it can be interpreted as the probability density and $j^\mu$ in general as the probability current.

My problem is now that this current is also the source of the electromagnetic field $A^\mu$ which we can see from the interaction term in the lagrangian:

$$
{\mathcal{L_I}} = e \bar \psi \gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu
$$

It couples the electromagnetic field to the current $j^\mu=\bar \psi \gamma^\mu \psi$ similarly to the Lagrangian of classical electrodynamics.

But is this probability current not fundamentally different from the electromagnetic current, which also can become an opposite sign for antiparticles?

For instance, if we take the particle spinor $(1,0,0,0)^T$ in Dirac basis, our charge would be $Q=(1,0,0,0)\cdot(1,0,0,0)^T=1$. For the respective antiparticle $(0,0,1,0)^T$ our charge would look like $Q=(0,0,1,0)\cdot(0,0,1,0)^T=1$. This shows that $j^\mu=\bar \psi \gamma^\mu \psi$ obviously can not be the electric 4-current since it produces the same electric charge for both particle and antiparticle, which seems as I mentioned above more like a probability current than an electric current.

So how can it be that this current is the source of the electromagnetic field?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that that $\psi(x)$ must be interpreted as field operator? Consequently $\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi$ is the OPERATOR representing the electromagnetic 4-current density and NOT a probabilty current. The Noether charge is given by $Q= \int d^3x j^0(x)$ and NOT by $j^0$. What does your favourite QFT/QED text book say?

Comment: Yes, I know that in quantum field theory the fields are regarded as operators. My question is rather aimed at the classical view of this field theory. But yes, even in this case the term probability density would not be suitable. Something like density would be more accurate. My point, however, was more about why you always get strictly positive values for j^0 if this is the charge density. And yes, you are right, in this case it would not be the Noether charge, but only its density, I formulated that incorrectly.

Comment: What Hyperon is trying to tell you is that $\bar\psi\psi$ is the probability density, and $\bar\psi\gamma^0\psi=\psi^\dagger\psi$ is the charge density (which is not strictly positive). You are just mistaken.

Comment: Ok thank you but why is $\psi^\dagger\psi$ not strictly positive? Don’t you just add the squares of the absolute values of the components which are always positive?

Comment: @Benny NO! The charge density operator corresponds to the normally ordered expression $: \bar{\psi} \gamma^0 \psi :$ being NOT strictly positive. It simply does not make sense to interpret the Dirac field $\psi(x)$ as some classical wave function with a probability interpretation. This was understood already in the early 30's of the last century! You find this in all good text books on QFT.

Comment: Ok so you mean it’s just not possible to use the Dirac Field as a classical Field theory?

Comment: You can but for it to be physically relevant, the field components are not complex numbers but complex Grassman numbers. Thus, even in this context the components do not commute, but anticommute.